# CASE on WHERE CLAUSE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a certain validation on my SQL Query.

```
WHERE USER_ACTIVE = 'Y'
```

But I want this validation to appear only when my FLAG is set to TRUE.

like, when FLAG is set to true, check user_active column.
when FLAG is false, then proceed without validation.

tried below but i think its not possible

```
WHERE CASE WHEN FLAG = 'TRUE' then USER_ACTIVE = 'Y' else ' ' END
```

Any reco?

Thanks IA!

Answer (score 2):

The logic is something like this:

```
WHERE USER_ACTIVE = 'Y' OR @FLAG <> 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Hi @gordon, what if my FLAG also need validation? like FLAG_VALUE (column) needs to be 'TRUE'  and FLAG_NAME(another_column) needs to be 'Customer A'

Comment: Gordon, I've never seen @ used in Oracle. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It is just a placeholder to distinguish the flag as variable from a column in the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CASE with WHERE. Just to point out, CASE statement only assigns values based on conditions. So, you need to make comparisons after the assignation is done. Try something like this:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN FLAG = 'TRUE' then USER_ACTIVE else ' ' END) = 'Y'
```

Comment: what if my FLAG also need validation? like FLAG_VALUE (column) needs to be 'TRUE' and FLAG_NAME(another_column) needs to be 'Customer A

Comment: You can add any such conditions on CASE statement. From what I understand, You can do this like (case when FLAG_VALUE(column) = 'TRUE' and FLAG_VALUE(another_column) = 'Customer A' then USER_ACTIVE else ' ' END) = 'Y'.